# C++ how to convert string characters to exact hex bytes

Tags: c++, string, hex, byte

To start off: I have an app that takes a byte array and loads assembly from it.

My idea, to prevent (easy)piracy, was to have an encrypted string on server, download it on client, decrypt it to get for example:
`std::string decrypted = "0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4";`

Then to convert from string to binary(byte array) so it would be

```
uint8_t binary[] = { 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4 };
```

And then continue as it was before, but after lots of googling I couldn't find much info on such direct conversion between regular string and byte array.
Thank you for any help! -Sarah

Comment: Is the binary string turned into a byte array intended to be executed?

Comment: Sorry for late answer @Eljay, the binary is actually a DLL file for embedding mono!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [std::stoul](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) to interpret a string as an unsigned integer. The unsigned integer can then be cast to a `uint8_t` type.

One method of parsing the entire string is by using a stringstream.

Code example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Input string and output vector
    std::string const decrypted{"0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4"};
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes;

    // Parse the string and fill the output vector
    std::istringstream decryptedStringStream{decrypted};
    std::string decryptedElement;
    while (getline(decryptedStringStream, decryptedElement, ','))
    {
        auto const byte = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(std::stoul(decryptedElement, nullptr, 16));
        bytes.push_back(byte);
    }

    // Print the results (in base 10)
    for (auto const &e : bytes)                                                                             
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(e) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) in a loop.

It gives you the ending position of the number, which you can then use to check if the string is at its end, or if it's a comma. If it's a comma skip it. Then call `std::stoi` again using the position as the string to parse.

It's not the most effective, but should work fine.

Comment: Interesting idea. Although I assume I'd have to make it load assembly from a signed integer, instead of a byte array, as stoi appears to be a function for converting strings into signed integers?
Unless you can somehow create a byte array out of a signed integer..

Comment: @xSarah Use a `std::vector<std::byte>` (or `std::vector<uint8_t>`) and append each number to it. Use the vector as your "byte array".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get rid of ", ". Then you can parse char by char, doing bitwise leftshift on every second char and saving as byte

```
char firstchar = HexCharToByte('5');
char secondchar = HexCharToByte('D');
char result = firstchar | (secondchar << 4);
printf("%%hhu", result); //93
```

Where HexCharToByte is (upper chars only):

```
char HexCharToByte(char ch) => ch > 57 ? (ch - 55) : (ch - 48);
```

This is fast enough method of parsing hex chars.

Comment: I seem to be misunderstanding on how to define your provided function, I'm also not sure how fast it would be as it's a very big string I am dealing with.

Comment: @xSarah, it'll be faster than std::stoi or anything else, i suppose. I've suggested method of fast parsing of hex chars (uppercase only). Then you just should do some basic work like removing ' ', ',' and "0x" to get only needed characters..